# How to unfreeze phone in Guided Access mode when triple click to prompt passcode won’t work? (iPhone 12)

Tags: iphone, guided-access

I put my iPhone into Guided Access. I tried to triple click to prompt my passcode, but it’s not showing up. Holding Volume Up and sleep is not working to shut down my phone.

Do I have to wait until the battery dies?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can just click once on the home button and use Touch ID. But this works if you have enabled Touch ID for Guided Access (Settings > Accessibility > Guided Access > Passcode Settings > Touch ID). You will need to wait until battery runs down this time and then you could enable Touch ID for next time.

Note to disable Guided Access and not waiting until battery runs down: Try long pressing Sleep button to shut down your iPhone, it should show a draggable button "slide to power off".